Error "COMMUNICATION_FAILURE" when trying to call parallel function modules
I have an ITAB with an EBELN column. For each unique EBELN I need to call BAPI_PO_GETDETAIL1. The BAPI Call takes a long time, so to improve performance I want to parallelize the calls. This is the Code that I got:
  METHOD main.
    "*Misc code*

    "Get number of free processes
    DATA processes TYPE i.
    CALL FUNCTION 'SPBT_INITIALIZE'
      EXPORTING
        group_name = 'parallel_generators'
      IMPORTING
        free_pbt_wps = processes.

    started_tasks = 0.
    DATA last_ebeln TYPE ekko-ebeln.
    LOOP AT itab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs>).
      IF <fs>-ebeln NE last_ebeln.
        WAIT UNTIL started_tasks LT processes - 1.
        DATA(taskid) = |{ sy-tabix }|.
        CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_PO_GETDETAIL1'
          STARTING NEW TASK taskid
          DESTINATION IN GROUP 'parallel_generators'
          CALLING read_finished ON END OF TASK
          EXPORTING
            purchaseorder    = <fs>-ebeln
            delivery_address = 'X'.
        .
        started_tasks = started_tasks + 1.
        last_ebeln = <fs>-ebeln.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.

    WAIT UNTIL started_tasks = 0.

    alv( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD read_finished.
    DATA addr TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapimepoaddrdelivery.
    DATA header TYPE bapimepoheader.

    RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION 'BAPI_PO_GETDETAIL'
      IMPORTING
        poheader = header
      TABLES
        poaddrdelivery = addr.

    set_address_and_distance(
      EXPORTING
        i_addr   = addr
      CHANGING
        c_header = header ).

    started_tasks = started_tasks - 1.

  ENDMETHOD.

My issue is that the WAIT UNTIL started_tasks LT processes - 1 works two times, but after the third time when started_tasks successfully gets below processes - 1, when the BAPI gets called, I get a short dump with COMMUNICATION_FAILURE on the BAPI call. My suspicion would be that it has something to do with waiting. I also searched on the internet what the error could mean, but found nothing that fixes the issue.
Can anybody tell me more about the error and what it means or has an idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

First of all, you should intercept the error and get the error text, as shown/explained in the ABAP documentation: RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION func ... EXCEPTIONS ... system_failure = ns MESSAGE smess communication_failure = nc MESSAGE cmess OTHERS = n_others.

@SandraRossi that would prevent the short dump itself, but does not help me fix the underlying issue

Also, the error occurs on the Call, not on the Receive

Do the same with CALL FUNCTION. If you can obtain the error text, it would help.

Thank you! I now understand what you mean. The error message was clear enough for me to fix it

FM 'SPBT_INITIALIZE' returns the number of free work processes in the parallel group at the time of the call, but this number can vary as you could not be the only person using this group. So your dump could be because there are no free work processes available.
The right approach is to get the current number of free work processes using FM 'SPBT_GET_CURR_RESOURCE_INFO' at each iteration of your loop.
